# How to use Remove-Item -Confirm:$false -Force properly in Windows PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

So, I am writing this script in PowerShell and I am required to delete a few files in APPDATA on Windows. I wrote this line of code and it doesn't remove the item silently. It asks for confirmation even after using $Confirm:false. How do I fix this issue?

My code:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $env:APPDATA\"Microsoft\teams\blob_storage" | Remove-Item -Confirm:$false -Force
```

I get this unwanted confirmation box every time I run the script:

[image: Screenshot of the confirmation box]

Comment: because the item you are trying to delete has child items inside it, you would need to supply the `-Recurse` switch as well after `-Force` that will allow you to delete child items without the prompt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your modified code. I hope it will work for you.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $env:APPDATA\"Microsoft\teams\blob_storage" | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
```